# How can I improve this mapping algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, mapping

I have a list of `n` items, that each have a product code and `m` people (that might be in several of the items).

Something like this:

```
items: [
  { code: 'Tuna', people: [ 'Adam', 'Eric' ] },
  { code: 'Corn', people: [ 'Eric' ] },
  ...
]
```

I want to map this to a list of distinct people and the products they have, or something like this:

```
people: {
  Adam: ['Tuna'],
  Eric: ['Tuna', 'Corn']
}
```

I've been beating myself up for the last two hours trying to come up with an elegant solution to what must be a pretty straight forward mapping algorithm.

I'm doing this in Java 8, so the stream API is all up for grabs. Order doesn't matter.

Here's my current best effort:

```
Map<Person, List<String>> partyProductMap = getItems().stream()
        .flatMap(item -> item.getPeople().stream())
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            person -> getItems().stream()
                    .filter(item -> item.getPeople().contains(person))
                    .map(item -> item.getProductCode())
                    .distinct()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
        ));
```

Would love to hear some ideas as to how I can improve this!

Answer (score 2):

My opinion is that most elegant solution is the simple one:

```
final Map<Person, Set<String>> partyProductMap = new HashMap<>();
for (final Item item : getItems())
    for (final Person person : item.getPeople()) {
        Set<String> codes = partyProductMap.get(person);
        if (codes == null) partyProductMap.put(person, codes = new HashSet<>());
        codes.add(item.code);
    }
```

Note: here is Set is used instead of List

Of course classes like Item/Person have proper implementations of hashCode, equals and probably compareTo

Answer (score 2):

what about this:

```
Map<Person, List<String>> partyProductMap = getItems().stream().
                flatMap(item -> item.getPeople().stream().map(
                        people -> Arrays.asList(
                                people, item.getProductCode()))).
                        collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.get(0),
                                Collectors.mapping(
                                        x-> x.get(1), Collectors.toList())));
```